# Why does Mirror Entity copy Flightmaster Dungar including the chosen quest?

Tags: hearthstone

I have learned that Mirror Entity does not copy Battlecry effects of minions, so I thought it would be perfect to play Flightmaster Dungar into my opponent's ME, but to my surprise their copy also got the flight plan (Plaguelands), even triggering before my own since they started their next turn with FD in play.

This surprised me greatly, since it seems inconsistent with how ME works for all other Battlecry cards.

Is there an explanation or logic to why it works like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the wiki page for [Mirror Entity](https://hearthstone.fandom.com/wiki/Mirror_Entity) ([Advanced rulebook — Playing/summoning a minion](https://hearthstone.fandom.com/wiki/Advanced_rulebook#Playing.2Fsummoning_a_minion) may also be helpful context):

> - Minions are copied in every detail, including current stats, card text, and enchantments.
> - As Mirror Entity minions are not played from the hand, any Battlecries possessed by them will not be activated. However, like all secrets, Mirror Entity takes effect after any Battlecries from the triggering minion.

So, the key here is that Mirror Entity doesn't *trigger* the minion's Battlecry, but it does copy the modifications *already made* by the Battlecry to that particular minion.

You should see the same results for any Battlecry minion which buffs or transforms itself.